# posting an array of two arrays with postman

Tags: php, arrays, postman

i'm trying to post something like the below code with postman to a PHP API.

```
$sizes = [['new_width' => 400, 'new_height' => 200], ['new_width' => 300, 'new_height' => 500]];
```

and there's also an image that i'm posting with the above array.
how can i use postman form-data to send that array with my file.

Answer (score 2):

Just like this, use `form-data`, form data key of array is like `sizes[0]['new_width']`.

[image]